# What is the situation for precog mutants outside Krakoa?

Tags: marvel, x-men, house-of-x

I have just read in "House of X" that Moira Kinross admonishes Magneto and Xavier about having mutants with precog abilities in Krakoa, because she fears people who can see into the future may bring instability onto the mutant nation.

However, this goes well against Xavier and Magneto's recent move of opening Krakoa to ***ALL*** mutants, even bringing in villains and giving a position of power to Frost and her mutant mafia.

If precogs are not allowed into Krakoa at all, how are they dealt with? What is their position about this and their allegiance to the mutant cause?

Comment: @Renan-Have you read Powers of X? This is tied into what happens in House of X

Comment: @Gothamite24 I have. Moira's rant about precogs happens after Powers of X.

Comment: I don't think most of the mutants on Krakoa know about the "no-precogs" rule. There was mention of another Xavier/Magneto falling-out, and those two have acted without consulting Moira before. I think when the issue arises, most of the Krakoans will expect the precog to be allowed access, and our decision-making trio won't be able to stand against the vox populi. Especially not when they're keeping their reason for the "no-precogs" rule a secret, and when Xavier and/or Magneto may secretly disagree with Moira. And they can't keep saying no to Mystique forever before she causes real trouble.